# How to find latitude and longitude?

Tags: measurements

[image]

I worked on the map and found out that point A is 60<sup>o</sup>N 120<sup>o</sup>W by looking at it, but the answer said that it A is suppose to be 30<sup>o</sup>N 90<sup>o</sup>W. For B, I got 30<sup>o</sup>S 60<sup>o</sup>W, but the answer said that B is 23<sup>o</sup>S 43<sup>o</sup>W. But points 23 and 43 are **not** on the map! What went wrong?

Comment: Your answers are correct.  Are you sure you are looking at the correct answer key?

Comment: You answers are indeed correct

Comment: I am looking at the correct answer key.

Comment: You got it right. Check that the supposed answers are indeed incorrect. If there is still a discrepancy, challenge your source to check and justify their answers. Be gracious in accepting their apology.